# PostgreSQL SequelizeDatabaseError: unrecognized configuration parameter "tables"

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When running the following code using [Sequelize 5.21.3](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) to get a list of all the tables in PostgreSQL 11.5 database:

```
sequelize.query('SHOW TABLES', {
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SHOWTABLES
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

we get the error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: unrecognized configuration parameter "tables"

What is the correct way to get a list of all the tables in the current PostgreSQL database using Sequelize?

**Full Code**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];

sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
sequelize.query('SHOW Tables', {
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SHOWTABLES
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    })
```

**Full Error Stack**

```
Executing (default): SHOW TABLES

Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: unrecognized configuration parameter "tables"
    at Query.formatError (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:366:16)
    at /Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:72:18
    at tryCatcher (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/nyxynyx/test/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

**config**

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "operatorsAliases": "0",
    "define": {
      "timestamps": false
    }
  },
...
```

Answer (score 6):

`SHOW TABLES` is MySQL syntax, that is not supported in Postgres.

If you are running psql, you can use the `\dt` command.

A more generic solution is to query [system view `information_schema.tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-tables.html) (which is available in more RDBMS):

```
select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.tables
```

You can also query [`pg_catalog.pg_tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html), which is Postgres-specific.